# Indirect reference to range in other sheet using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

In `Sheet1` of my Excel file I have the following input:

```
           A              B    
1   'Sheet2'!J:O      
2
```

In `Cell A1` is the range that should be hidden in `Sheet2` when I run this VBA:

```
Sub Hiding_Columns()
Sheet1.Range(Range("A1")).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
End Sub
```

However, with this code I  get `runtime error 1004.`

What do I need to change to make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the following:

```
Range(Sheet1.Range("A1").Value).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

The way you have it is (when `Sheet1` is the active sheet) equivalent to:

```
Sheet1.Range("'Sheet2'!J:O").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

and that won't work because you've got the sheets mixed together.